# Desktop GUI Design/Prototype/Mockup/Wireframe

Tags: gui-design, mockups

I'm working on a project at the moment and I'm currently looking for some sources regarding creating GUI mockups. In my case, I'm creating basic diagrams with the intended layout of the design to ensure it will work correctly and consistently.

What is this called? I've seen various names for it, including:

1. GUI Prototyping
2. GUI Mockups
3. GUI Wireframes

Which applies to my situation and are there any good resources to reaffirm my decision to create these diagrams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above terms will work.  I don't see a fast and hard rule for any different nuances between the terms.

One thing to note is that because there is fuzziness in terms, you want to be ready to set expectations with users and customers for what you're doing and what you want to get out of the experience.  You want to be able to tell them what they can expect to get out of it, and who they should bring to give you feedback.  You'll need real users, not managers in charge of users.

There are a TON of sites out there on why UI prototyping is a good practice:

http://www.ambysoft.com/essays/userInterfaceDesign.html

Is both good practices and why UI prototyping is so important.

http://www.foruse.com/contents/index.htm

is also a site by leading UI guy and has a TON of papers on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these terms describe what you are doing. Each phrase can and does apply whether you've done the design as a pencil sketch, Photoshop image or semi working application.

Check out our [sister site for User Experience questions](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) for more information on these.